# Перенос строк в списке xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Уже битый час хочу добавить перенос строки в список,подскажите как это сделать

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Info"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Cars">
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Cars"/>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Saller">
    <li> 
      <a href="#">
        <xsl:value-of select="Saller"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="Price"/>
      </a>
           <br/><!-- не работает  -->
    </li>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Судя по разметке, должен получиться html. Между тем, я вижу `output method="xml"`.

Comment: покажите сам xml и пример результата. потому что `apply-templates select="Cars"` внутри `template match="Cars"` выглядит странно. я смог подобрать xml, на котором ваш xslt нормально работает. Кстати, `Saller` - это скорее всего Seller?

Comment: <![CDATA[]]> попробуйте использовать. Может вам поможет ответ на этот вопрос?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14567794/using-br-tag-within-xml-for-xslt

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986297/line-break-in-xml

Comment: http://p2p.wrox.com/xslt/48167-how-insert-br-table-xml-xsl.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавил в начало документа  `<xsl:output method="html"/>` вместо `<xsl:output method="xml"/>` и тег `<br>` заработал.